# How to hide the first column using a QSortFilterProxyModel with a Qabstractitemmodel

Tags: qt, pyqt, qtreeview, qabstractitemmodel, qsortfilterproxymodel

In widget my implementation, `model` the source model (subclassed from a `QAbstractItemModel`), `proxy_model` (subclassed from QSortFilterProxyModel) the proxy, and `tree` (QTreeView) the tree representing the model.

I want to hide the first column.
I tried to use `tree.hideColumn(0)`, the the tree is shown flat.

- If I subclass `filterAcceptsColumn` in the proxy to return True only for the second column,, then no rows are shown.
  I believe this is because the parent/child relationships are anchored on the first column in the indexes, and when the proxy ask for the number of rows for a given index of column 1, the model returns 0 (which is the expected behavior in the model implementation if I understood well).
- If I set `rowCount` to return non 0 values in the model for columns index > 0, I can see the tree and the rows, but then the model is not passing the `QAbstractItemModelTester` test with the folloing error:

```
qt.modeltest: FAIL! childIndex != childIndex1 () returned FALSE
```

I understand well that in the tree model, child index must be attached to a single parent index (the first column).
But how am I supposed to be hiding the first column in a proxy model if the parent child relationship of the source model are not retained by the proxy if the first column is filtered? I feel it is a "bug" from the proxy, or I missed something !

Do anyone know the proper way of filtering/hiding the first column in the tree view without losing the parent/child information, and still validating a qmodel implementation?

Thanks !

Comment: Well, that's a bit tricky. The problem is that, as you already found out, a tree model (at least in Qt) only considers child items for the first column of each parent index. The problem becomes even more complex if you think about those child items: should the model hide the first column even for them? Proper implementation might become really hard (and possibly buggy), so I'd suggest trying to "hack" your way around it: since I'm assuming you're going to need that only for display purpose, what if you just return the column+1 data of each top level item?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm not sure how the hack you propose would make a difference..?

Comment: The idea is not to hide the first column, but to show the data of the column next to the requested one, and eventually hide the last one instead. In this way, the parent/child relation is kept (since the model structure is always the same and indexes are always referred to the original column), the only difference is that the displayed contents are shifted by one column.

Comment: If I got it well, you get then an empty column in your treeview, right ?.

Comment: Well, theoretically yes, but then you can hide *that* last column, without worrying about the structure. Be aware that I've not tested it, it's just an idea that popped into my mind, but it seems to make sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proper and correct implementation would at least require the proxy to create indexes for the parent of the *second* column, requiring correct implementation of `index()`, `parent()`, `mapToSource()` and `mapFromSource()`. For tree models that can be really tricky.

If the source model is not too complex and all its functions are correctly implemented, a possible workaround could be to just override the `data()` (and `headerData`) of the proxy and always return the sibling of the next column.

The following test is done with a simple QStandardItemModel, but I don't think using a QAbstractItemModel should be any different, as long as it's correctly implemented.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class ColumnSwapProxy(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        return super().data(index.sibling(index.row(), index.column() + 1), role)

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
            section += 1
        return super().headerData(section, orientation, role)

class Test(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        layout.addWidget(self.combo)

        self.tree = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        layout.addWidget(self.tree)
        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.createTree(self.model.invisibleRootItem())

        self.tree.setModel(self.model)
        self.model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(
            ['Root', 'Fake root'] + ['Col {}'.format(c) for c in range(2, 6)])
        self.tree.header().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)

        self.proxy = ColumnSwapProxy()
        self.proxy.setSourceModel(self.model)

        self.combo.addItem('Base model', self.model)
        self.combo.addItem('First column hidden', self.proxy)
        self.combo.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.setModel)

    def setModel(self):
        model = self.combo.currentData()
        self.tree.setModel(model)
        lastColumn = self.model.columnCount() - 1
        self.tree.header().setSectionHidden(lastColumn, model == self.proxy)

    def createTree(self, parent, level=0):
        for r in range(10):
            first = QtGui.QStandardItem('Root {} (level {})'.format(level + 1, r + 1))
            if level < 2 and not r & 3:
                self.createTree(first, level + 1)
            row = [first]
            for c in range(5):
                row.append(QtGui.QStandardItem(
                    'Column {} (level {})'.format(c + 2, level + 1)))
            parent.appendRow(row)


import sys
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = Test()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```